# To find the differential equation of $Y=\alpha x+\beta x^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$Y=\alpha x+\beta x^2$

when i try to find it any one of the parameter comes into the final equation ..how to eliminate both the parameters .i tried every possible way i can similarly the second one i am stuck with is

$y=Ae^{^{3x}}+Be^{5x}$

Please help me how to proceed further after taking two derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

For the first case find $y' = \alpha+\beta (2x)$....(1).   And then $y'' = 2\times \beta$....(2). Substitute  (2) in (1) and get the expression for $\alpha $ and then substitute for $\alpha $ and $\beta $ in the original expression and get the resultant expression. Similarly proceed for the second case. First find $y'$ and $y''$ and then find the resultant expression. Hope it helps.